# Лишние слэши после обработки RewriteRule

Tags: .htaccess

Есть такое `RewriteRule ^blabla(/.*)*$ $1`, после обработки данного *rule* после домена добавляется 3 слэша. Не подскажете как можно это решить? Работает у меня он примерно так: из `mysite.ru/blabla/page.html` делает `mysite.ru///page.html`, а если `mysite.ru/blabla/`, то получается `mysite.ru///`.

Comment: Покажите весь .htaccess, потому что такой редирект `RewriteRule ^blabla(/.*)$ $1 [L,R=301]` отрабатывает нормально, без возникновения дополнительных слешей.

Answer (score 1):

попробуйте вынести `/` за скобки. да и квантификатор `*` после группы, мне кажется, лишний:

```
^blabla/(.*)$
```

это уберёт как минимум один `/`, а второй «появляется», видимо, откуда-то из другого места.

Answer (score 1):

## Искоренить повторяющиеся слеши (///) из url

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)/{2,}(.*)$
RewriteRule (.*) %1/%2 [R=301,L]
```

использую такой вариант. это правило внести в htaccess надо.